# Using wsgen to generate JAX-WS web service related classes, WSDL and XSD

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, command-prompt, wsgen

I am trying out a Hello World JAX-WS web service (a Document styled, instead of RPC) in eclipse. I am following [this tut](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/).

Here is my project setup:

[image]

Now I want to create web service support classes for deployment of web service using `wsgen` as explained in the tut. So in windows command prompt I navigated to my apps' bin directory (`>cd bin`)
and then executed the given command:

[image]

So in `bin\com\Mahesh\ws\jaxws` it created following four files

- GetHelloWorldAsString.class
- GetHelloWorldAsString.java
- GetHelloWorldAsStringResponse.class
- GetHelloWorldAsStringResponse.java

Since source files are put in `bin\com\Mahesh\ws\jaxws` folder but not in `src\com\Mahesh\ws\jaxws`, doing package refresh in eclipse does not show newly generated source files in Package Explorer

**1.** I want these source files to be generated in `src\com\Mahesh\wssrc` - an empty package you can see in first image.

**2.** Also when I published this web service and saw its WSDL file, I realized a separate XSD is getting created behind the scenes. So I want to use wsgen to create this WSDL and XSD and put it in another empty package `src\com\Mahesh\rsc` you can see in first image.

After reading `wsgen`'s help I found these two options:

- `-r <directory>`: resource destination directory, specify where to place resouce files such as WSDLs
- `-s <directory>`: specify where to place generated source files

But still I am unable to figure out how I can accomplish this.

**3.** Also the tut says:

> Wait, when you run the end point publisher, you will hits following error message :
>   `Wrapper class com.mkyong.ws.jaxws.GetHelloWorldAsString is not found. 
>       Have you run APT to generate them?`

However I did not get any such error and my endpoint was published without any  error. So do we still need to explicitly generate classes for web service deployment using `wsgen` or this is handled by JAX-WS internally.

Comment: Deploy your Web service on servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) or some application server (e.g. Glassfish) and get rid of all unnecessary `wsgen` stuff. You are aware that tutorial you are following is for Web services written as standalone applications (and this is very rarely case in practice)?

Comment: Yes I know that tut builds web services as a    standalone application. and Do you mean instead of using `wsgen`, deploy it on the web server and get the necessary files?

Comment: Exactly. If you deploy it, all necessary files will be auto-generated and you don't have to take care about them. Additionally, in that case you won't use `Endpoint.publish(..)` method, but just annotate your service appropriately and server will take care about the rest (except in case of Tomcat, there you'll have to supply some configuration files as well).

Comment: Yeah I know that but I just want to know how `wsgen` works in this specific situation and in fact if this is possible with `wsgen`